# how do I add settings to wordpress add page

Tags: wordpress

I am working with Wordpress 3.6

I've seen some plugins that add settings to the page you use to add/edit pages on your site.

How can I add my own settings to this page as well?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean. Could you post an example or give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Use [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

Comment: Thanks Brasofilo. I think that is what I'm looking for. jakobhans: If you have used WPML, for example, when you build a page it adds an area that you can add translations and do other things.